# C# Virtual Function

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have a question on below class.

`Photo` class inherits from `Form` and has an image so when I create the object of `Photo` class as per its constructor it draws the image because of virtual `Drawer` method.

There is `BorderedPhoto` class which inherits from `Photo` class and also has override method `Drawer()` which sets border around the photo image.

The program is running fine but my confusion is when i create the object of `BorderedPhoto` class by reffering Photo class object then why it is called the override `Drawer()` of Bordered class even though it is not explicitly calling it.

```
class Photo:Form
{
    Image image;
    public Photo()
    {
        image= new Bitmap(@"C:\Jug_7.jpg");

        this.Text = "My Water Jug";
        this.Paint+= new PaintEventHandler(Drawer);
    }
    public virtual void Drawer(object source, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 20, 20);
    }
}
class BorderedPhoto : Photo
{
    Photo photo;
    Color color;
    public BorderedPhoto(Photo p, Color c)
    {
        photo = p;
        color = c;
    }
    public override void Drawer(object source, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.Drawer(source, e);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color, 10), 25, 15, 215, 225);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using the `BorderedPhoto` class? Please show the usage.

Comment: yes show the usage and object creation

Comment: "when i create the object of BorderedPhoto class by referring Photo class object" <-- That makes no sense. Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

> The program is running fine but my confusion is when i create the object of BorderedPhoto class by refering Photo class object then why it is called the override Drawer() of Bordered class eventhough it is not explicitly calling it.

so I take that to mean something like...

```
Photo p = new BorderedPhoto();
```

Well, that's kinda the whole point of polymorphism.  If you had to qualify the underlying type when calling a polymorphic method what would be the point?  This behavior allows you to work with different implementations through a shared interface.

Furthermore, since you call `base.Drawer(source, e);` inside of your override, the base class implementation will be called as well.